# Is monomorphism going in both directions sufficient for isomorphism?

Tags: ct.category-theory, universal-algebra

In category theory, it seems that a monomorphism from $A$ to $B$ and one from $B$ to $A$ should be enough to guarantee isomorphy, but it doesn't seem to be so. (If I'm right then there's something fishy with the standard definition of "subobject")

So here's the counterexample I thought up, please explain where I went wrong.

Consider a category consisting of 2 objects $A$ and $B$. There is a monomorphism $\phi: A \to B$ and another $\psi : B \to A$. "Close" this under composition in much the same way you do when defining a free group (that is, no non-trivial identities are allowed). I claim that this does not guarantee isomorphism. All morphisms are monic, since no identities hold, so the condition for monomorphism is trivially satisfied.

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Nothing is wrong, it is simply not true that monomorphisms in both directions guarantee isomorphism. A very concrete example is given by considering the intervals (0,1) and [0,1] in the category of topological spaces. I don't understand your comment about the standard definition of a subobject.

Comment: Another example is that  free group of finite rank $>1$ contains free subgroups of any finite (and countable) rank. Hence, one may take two free groups of different finite ranks $>1$.

Comment: In the category of sets, however, it is true that when two sets inject into each other, then there is a bijection. This is the Cantor-Bernstein-Schroeder theorem. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cantor%E2%80%93Bernstein%E2%80%93Schroeder_theorem. But it fails in many other naturally arising categories. MO member John Goodrick has investigated this quite a lot.

Comment: Very nice, dan: my example with free groups seems complicated in contrast. My only consolation is that it might be an interesting  result to know and that I am in the excellent company of Torsten  (whom I hadn't read when I started answering)

Comment: The comment about subobjects is this. The definition of a subobject of an object A is: an object B with a monomorphism from B to A. So in my example, A is a subobject of B and B a subobject of A, but they aren't isomorphic. This seems weird, right?

Comment: There is a standard game, that I have associated with Noah Snyder at Secret Blogging Seminar, but I've lost the link.  The game goes: for each category you come across in nature, ask if both-ways monos implies that there is an iso.  SET?  Yes.  TOP? No.

Comment: http://mathoverflow.net/questions/1058/when-does-cantor-bernstein-hold

Comment: @Seamus: to see why it's not weird, contemplate the example of [0,1] and (0,1) above.  A composite of monomorphisms [0,1] → (0,1) → [0,1] will end up embedding [0,1] as a *proper* subject of itself, eg as [1/4,3/4].

The categorical definition of subobject is more flexible than the set-theoretic — so it accommodates mathematical practice more naturally, eg “$\mathbb{N} \subset \mathbb{R}$” — but it shows that “$A$ is a subobject of $B$” isn't just a statement about $A$ and $B$, but also about some assumed map $A$ → $B$. [cont'd in next comment]

Comment: Often it's clear what map we mean, and so we can get away with leaving it unmentioned.  But when it's not assumed, you may need to make it explicit!  I think the intuition behind your weirdness may be something like the fact “if there are monomorphisms *A* → *B* → *A*, and their composite is the identity $1_A$, *then* these monos are isos”.  (Proving this is a nice exercise!)  In terms of subobjects: “if *A* is a s.o. of *B*, and *B* is a subobject of *A*, and these are compatible with our standard way of thinking of *A* as a subobject of itself, then *A* and *B* are isomorphic”.


Comment: @seamus, the definition of subobject is slightly more subtle than what you reproduce it as; a subobject is an equivalence class of monomorphisms $S\to X$, where equivalence is given by the monomorphisms mutually factoring through each other; in other words, 
$S\to X$ and $T\to X$ represent the same subobject precisely if there are maps $S\to T$ and $T\to S$ such that $S\to X = S\to T\to X$ and $T\to X = T\to S\to X$.
These maps have to be monomorphisms, and then you can take up Peter's argument above for the remainder of the argument.

Comment: Right, so the problem is more that I'm misunderstanding what sort of work the categorical subobject idea is doing. But I'm glad I was right about monomorphisms...

Answer (score 4):

Dear Seamus, an example of non-isomorphic objects mutually monomorphing into each other is the following, in the category of groups ( I haven't tried to follow your sketch of construction).

Consider the free group on two generators $F_2$. Its commutator subgroup $C\subset F_2$ is a free group on denumerably many generators: $C=F_\infty$. This can be proved elegantly by using topological covering spaces [you can look it up in Massey's Introduction to Algebraic Topology for example].

So you have monomorphisms 
$F_2 \hookrightarrow F_\infty$ and $F_\infty \hookrightarrow  F_2$, although  $F_2$ and  $F_\infty$ are not isomorphic, since their abelianizations are free $\mathbb Z$ modules on respectively two and denumerably many generators.

I have used that monomorphisms in the category of groups coincide with injective morphisms, which is a not trivial but true result [ Jacobson, Basic Algebra, vol.II, Prop 1.1]

Comment: Regarding the last paragraph: If $C \to Set$ is a faithful functor which has a left-adjoint, then $f$ is a monomorphism in $C$ if and only if it is injective.

Comment: A little  more "hard" is the analogous assert about epimorphisms  (see Mitchell Theory of Categories$ p. 38). 

Answer (score 2):

Your counterexample is correct; indeed it is the universal one, every other counterexample comes from a functor defined on your category. For a counterexample in the category of fields, see my answer here [Counterexamples in Algebra?](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/29006/counterexamples-in-algebra/29076#29076).

You seem to be worried about subobjects. If $X$ is an object and $U,V \leq X$ are subobjects such that $U \leq V$ and $V \leq U$, then $U = V$. The reason is that the morphisms $U \to V$ and $V \to U$ over $X$ are uniquely determined (since $V \to X, U \to X$ are monomorphisms). Likewise are the compositions $U \to V \to U, V \to U \to V$ uniquely determined, namely the identity. Thus $U = V$. Thus you don't get into trouble.

Comment: So to get this straight: the definition of subobject requires that the monomorphism be unique?

Comment: I don't know which mono you mean, but nowhere uniqueness of something is required.

Comment: I don't know what you mean by "the morphisms ... over X are uniquely determined"

Comment: Here's the worry: in the two object category I defined above, each of A and B is a subobject of the other, but they are not isomorphic. Is this just a case where the categorical notion of "subobject" doesn't make sense, or have I misunderstood?

Comment: you're right, but this is not really a misbehavior of subobjects. since when you *fix* some object $X$, then the subobjects of $X$ behave well (see my answer).

Comment: OK. But in general it is not true that subobjecthood determines and antisymmetric relation? But in most cases of interest, it will...

Comment: No, Schröder-Bernstein does NOT hold in most cases.

Comment: In category theory one has to get away from thinking of objects in the way that sets are defined in ZFC. All you know about are arrows, not about how objects are 'contained in' other objects in some global sense. But once a given object is fixed, then considering subobjects of that one object is much easier and nicer. The full subcategory of C/X consisting of the monos is a poset, which means that monos representing the same subobject are canonically isomorphic _in this slice category_, but not in C.

Answer (score 2):

I should state first that this reply has only to do with the above mentioned ideas in the category of models of a first order theory.

John Goodrick's work is referenced in Joel's post above, and I have heard John Goodrick speak about this at least once. Specifically, John mentioned the following (and a lot more that I didn't write down):

Fix some countable, complete first-order theory, $T$. Suppose $T$ has the following property: Whenever we are given two models $\mathcal M_1$ and $\mathcal M_2$ of $T$ which have elementary embeddings into each other, then  $\mathcal M_1 \cong \mathcal M_2.$

Then $T$ is superstable and nonmultidimensional (and I know if John replies to this, he can mention many other things, but I don't remember now). In the case that $T$ is actually $\omega -$stable, nonmultidimensional implies the bi-embedding property stated in the above paragraph.

Answer (score 1):

One of the simplest example , lightest in structure and very easy in checking is :

In the category of monoids take the canonical injection $i$ from $(N,+,0)$ to $(Z,+,0)$.

This is a monomorphism that is also an epimorphism yet not an iso ($i$ is not a surjection).

($N$ and $Z$ are the positive integers and integers respectively)

Comment: Not the same as what the original question was asking for

Comment: You are perfectly right. I reread the question which now seems new and interesting. The only positive point for my miss-answer would be to try to describe the type of question that include both? 