# Complete non-isomorphic lattices with injective complete homomorphisms between them?

Tags: order-theory, lattice-theory

Are there complete lattices $L, K$ such that

- $L\not\cong K$;
- there are injective complete lattice homomorphisms $i:L\to K$ and $j: K\to L$

?

Comment: This question seems related http://mathoverflow.net/questions/1058/when-does-cantor-bernstein-hold/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $A=[0,\omega_0]$ and $K=[0,1]$ be closed intervals of the ordinals and the real numbers with natural orderings. Let $L=A\times K$ be equipped with the lexicographic order where the $A$ coordinate is more important. Then both $L$ and $K$ are complete and the injective homomorphisms are easy to construct. To see that $L\not\cong K$ as ordered sets observe that $K$ is connected in its order topology while $L$ is not.

**Edit:** Please unaccept this answer so that I can delete it. The correct answer is provided by Eric Wofsey. The $K$ admits no complete embedding into $L$ as such an embedding would have to preserve the least and the largest elements (inf and sup of the empty set).

Comment: How do you get a _complete_ injective homomorphism $K\to L$?  For a simpler example that does work, just take $K=\{0\}\cup[1,2]$ and $L=\{-1,0\}\cup[1,2]$.

Comment: Oh, yes. Or even simpler: $K=[1,2]$ and $L=\{0\}\cup[1,2]$. Referring to your question: this is the identity $[0,1]\to\{0\}\times[0,1]$.

Comment: That is not a homomorphism; it does not preserve the maximal element.

Comment: I see - I missed that point. So we need both $K$ and $L$ to be disconnected. Please write your answer and I will delete mine.

Comment: @Dominic van der Zypen please unaccept this answer so that I can delete it.

Answer (score 4):

For a simple example with complete total orders, take $L=\{0\}\cup[1,2]$ and $K=\{-1,0\}\cup[1,2]$.