# The scope of a "strong Cantor-Bernstein" property

Tags: ct.category-theory, linear-algebra, lo.logic, model-theory

*This question is of course related to [this earlier MO question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/1058/when-does-cantor-bernstein-hold), but I don't believe is answered by the posts there.*

My favorite proof of the Cantor-Schroeder-Bernstein theorem actually establishes something stronger: if $f:A\rightarrow B$ and $g:B\rightarrow A$ are injections, then there is a bijection $h:A\rightarrow B$ contained in the union $f\cup g^{-1}$. This is an extremely strong property. For example, let $A$ and $B$ each be copies of $\mathbb{N}$ as a linear order and consider the embeddings $f:A\rightarrow B:x\mapsto 2x$ and $g: B\rightarrow A: x\mapsto 3x$. Then $A\cong B$, but the unique isomorphism from $A$ to $B$ can't be pieced together from $f$ and $g$ in any reasonable way, let alone literally being $\subseteq f\cup g^{-1}$.

I'm interested in any situations where a strengthening of CSB along the above lines holds. To keep things reasonably narrow, the following potential CSB strengthening for vector spaces seems natural to consider but unlikely to hold:

> Suppose $f:V\rightarrow W, g:W\rightarrow V$ are linear embeddings between disjoint vector spaces over a field $k$. Let $E$ be the equivalence relation on $V\sqcup W$ generated by (the graphs of) $f$ and $g$. For $a\in V$ (resp. $b\in W$) let $\widehat{a}=\langle W\cap [a]_E\rangle_W$ (resp. $\widehat{b}=\langle V\cap [b]_E\rangle_V$), where "$\langle \cdot\rangle_U$" means "span in $U$."
>
> Must there be an isomoprhism $h:V\cong W$ such that for all $a\in V$ and all $b\in W$ we have $h(a)\in \widehat{a}$ and $h^{-1}(b)\in\widehat{b}$?

Comment: Banach's improved version of the CSB theorem says that, for any mappings (not necessarily injections) $f:A\to B$ and $g:B\to A$, there are partitions $A=A_1\sqcup A_2$ and $B=B_1\sqcup B_2$ such that $f(A_1)=B_1$ and $g(B_2)=A_2$. Not that this has any bearing on your question; I just mention it because I like to plug Banach's theorem.

Comment: @bof Indeed, that's a great theorem!

Comment: Rolling on @bof's comment: there's also the not-sufficiently-well-known Four Sets Theorem: for every $f : X \to X$ there is a disjoint partition of $X$ in four (possibly empty) parts $X_0,X_1,X_2,X_3$ where $X_0$ is the set of fixed-points of $f$ and $f[X_i] \cap X_i = \varnothing$ for $i=1,2,3$.

Comment: @PaceNielsen That's not an isomorphism. It sends $5$ to $10$, for example. (Note that these are linear orders, not just sets.)

Comment: Oops, somehow misread that.  I deleted my comment.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For infinite-dimensional vector spaces over any field, there is no such isomorphism.  We will handle the countable-dimensional case, as the others are similar.  Let $V$ be generated by the linearly independent vectors $v_0,v_1,\ldots$, and similarly let $W$ be generated by the linearly independent vectors $w_0,w_1,\ldots$.  Let $f$ be the linear map uniquely determined by taking $v_i\mapsto w_{i+1}$, and similarly let $g$ be the linear map uniquely determined by taking $w_i\mapsto v_{i+1}$.  (These might be termed "right-shift maps".)  They are both injective.

Let $h\colon V\to W$ be any vector space isomorphism.

Now, $[v_0]_{E}=\{v_0,w_1,v_2,w_3,\ldots\}$ and $[v_1]_{E}=\{w_0,v_1,w_2,v_3,\ldots\}$.  So, if $h$ is supposed to have the stated property, then $h(v_0)\in {\rm Span}(w_1,w_3,\ldots)$, while $h^{-1}(w_0)\in {\rm Span}(v_1,v_3,\ldots)$.

However, $[v_0+h^{-1}(w_0)]_{E}$ does not have $w_0$ in the support of any element.  So, we cannot have $w_0$ in the support of $$h(v_0+h^{-1}(w_0))=h(v_0)+w_0\in w_0+{\rm Span}(w_1,w_3,\ldots),$$ which gives us the needed contradiction.